# Error when trying to reset git HEAD

Tags: git

I a trying to delete the last commit from the local repository by using the

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

command.
However I get the following error:

```
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD~1'.
```

I get

```
(Filename too long)
```

for several files. How can I avoid this? I am on Windows

Comment: Maybe `git log; git reset <sha-of-HEAD~ >`? Or the barbaric `git checkout HEAD~; git branch -D master; git checkout -b master`.

Comment: What are the filenames for those files giving the trouble?

Comment: I'm usually using for this purpose `git reset --hard HEAD^`, however I cannot tell why your way isn't working

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but what is going on in your working directory? Is it clean?

Answer (score 7):

Try to see if those error persists with:

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Make sure to use the [latest git-for-windows (2.7.0)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), and you should not even need that option.